# Force PRISM to use another instance of UnityContainer

Tags: unity-container, prism

I have UnityContainer in my app yet. Now I want to add use of PRISM to my app and I want PRISM to use my Container instead of its inner one defined in bootstrapper. Or I would also satisfied if I could create some kind of link between these two containers in order  when I call MyContainer.Resolve() it could redirect this call to PRISM's container and resolve type that registered in PRISM, i.e RegionManager.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need to override the `CreateContainer()` method in your application's bootstrapper and return your own `IUnityContainer`:

```
protected override IUnityContainer CreateContainer()
{
    // return your container here...
}
```